# Use any character as delimiter on std::getline()

Tags: c++, stdout, stdin, getline

I'm trying to count the spaces `' '` at the beginning of a line from a file stored into a string. 
The problem is that i don't know how to tell to `std::getline()` to stop when find any character distinct to `' '`.

```
std::getline(file_input, string_target, 'Any_character_except_space');
```

Comment: You're probably approaching that problem wrong. One hammer I could think of is `std::regex`.

Comment: `std::getline` won't do that. Write your own function, reading one character at a time until you find a character that matches your criteria.

Comment: You could look for a *space* and count the number of times `std::getline(f, s, ' ');` reads an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use *any character except space* as delimiter for [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), none of the signatures allows so.

What you could do is for instance:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(file_input,line);
auto pos = std::find_if_not(std::begin(line),std::end(line),[](char c) {
        return std::isspace(c);
     // or c == ' '
     // or whatever condition you need
    } );
size_t space_count = std::distance(std::begin(line),pos);
```

Here's a [full example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91f7c7e749d5b0cc).

Comment: Why the conditional? If `pos == std::end(line)`, then the string is entirely spaces, and `std::distance(std::begin(line), pos)` will return the length of the string, which is also the number of spaces at the beginning of the string, in that case.

Comment: @Benjamin Seems you're right. I had a slightly different logic in mind.